# Catch-all mail server, no forwarding

Tags: linux, postfix, email

This is an internal server (lets call it **tools**) on the same network as a set of test servers (for web applications). I want emails coming out of the test servers to arrive in the qa@tools account (no matter what their actual destination was). I do not want tools to forward anything anywhere.

I've got postfix and squirrelmail configured, and I can send mail to qa@tools just fine. Right now if I set the mail_host to tools on the web apps (on the test servers) - and they send mail to user@example.com via tools - tools will say 'no forwarding' and reject them. Which is fine, except that QA staff can't then examine them because they're lost.

I tried adding `always_bcc = qa@tools` to my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` ... but that didn't get me copies of those rejected emails.

There must be a simple answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `recipient_canonical_maps` to map all recipients, regardless of their original destination, to an address.

In `main.cf`:

```
recipient_canonical_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical.pcre
```

In `/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical.pcre`:

```
/.*/ qa@tools.yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like postfix has been misconfigured?

Could you maybe check the list of domains that postfix will listen and accept mail for? If it is configured to accept all mail destined for @tools, it should not complain about forwarding it on to anyone else.

Comment: I've edited my question a little for clarity. I don't want anything forwarded through this server, that behavior is correct. mydestination=tools ... I just want all mail dumped into the qa@tools account.

Comment: But if you don't want mail to be forwarded and you send a mail to tools server destined for @example.com, the tools server can only forward it on, because it is not supposed to process mail for example.com.